# Set application state in iframe only

Tags: java, iframe, wicket, wicket-1.6

Ok, what I'm trying to do is come up with a way to apply certain application settings (CSS to be exact) but only within an iframed version of the app.

If you've used Wordpress, I'm basically trying to implement a version of the theme live preview where it opens a version of the application in an iframe with theme changes made only to that instance of the site. I think it (Wordpress) does this by using JavaScript to change all the links to AJAX POST requests with the chosen theme as part the parameters.

I was thinking I might be able to do something similar by adding a page parameter (`themePreview` or something similar), detect that and apply the temporary (session) style properties. I already have a custom `CssResourceReference` that does this albeit without the page parameter detection though that seems simple enough.

My main problem is, I want the user to be able to navigate around the site within the iframe. To do so, I would need to maintain, persist or somehow inject the `themePreview` page parameter into all page requests when it is already set.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this or alternatively, have a better idea?

Comment: Does it mean you want to get the value of themePreview from the session to decide which CSS file is to use?

Comment: @MartinStrejc No. I'm wanting the `themePreview` to be a flag that only applies whilst navigating around the iframed version of the site. I'm thinking a `PageParameter` would apply best. It cannot be stored in the session as then it would apply outside the iframe which is not what I want

Comment: OK, so I use in my applications a general ancestor of all pages (e.g. MyBasePage) and when I need a general functionality it is implemented here very easy, including anything after PageParameters. Also I use it the same way as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in wicket work by calling the urlFor method of the request cycle. This includes a URL renderer which all URLs are passed through when they are being generated.

If you:

- Write a sub class for `UrlRenderer` to add your `themePreview` parameter to all urls if it was a parameter in the request
- Write a sub class of `RequestCycle` and override the `newUrlRenderer()` to return your `UrlRenderer`.
- Create your own implementation of `IRequestCycleProvider` to provide your custom `RequestCycle`
- In your application class, in the `init` method, call `setRequestCycleProvider` passing your custom `IRequestCycleProvider`.

This way, if the `themePreview` parameter is present in a request, it will be automatically added to any URL that is generated and so will be present on any link within your iframe.